# How can I find out our customer's favourite brand using a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to generate a table (or query result) in this form

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| Email               | Favourite Brand ID  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| customer@gmail.com  |                  89 |
+-                   -+-                   -+
| another@gmail.com   |                 193 |
+-                   -+-                   -+
```

I have managed to write a query that generates a list of unique brand ID's with customer email addresses and the number of times that customer has purchased that brand. The results look something like this:

```
+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Email               | Brand ID  | CountOfOrders |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
| customer@gmail.com  |        89 |            10 |
+-                   -+-         -+-             -+
| another@gmail.com   |       193 |            32 |
+-                   -+-         -+-             -+
| duplicate@gmail.com |        20 |             2 |
+-                   -+-         -+-             -+
| duplicate@gmail.com |        47 |             5 |
+-                   -+-         -+-             -+
```

Obviously `duplicate@gmail.com` has purchased from BrandID 20 twice and BrandID 47 5 times which is why they appear twice. Most customers have purchased from more than one brand.

From this information how can I construct a query to get the brand ID they have purchased from the most? I have tried the following but it just times out:

```
SELECT [table1].Email, [table1].Brand, [table1].CountOfBrand
FROM [Customer Brand Purchases] AS [table1]
GROUP BY [table1].Email, [table1].Brand, [table1].CountOfBrand
WHERE [table1].CountOfBrand=(
    SELECT TOP 1 [table2].CountOfBrand 
    FROM [Customer Brand Purchases] AS [table2] 
    WHERE [table2].Email = [table1].Email 
    ORDER BY [table2].CountOfBrand DESC
);
```

Oh and I have to use Microsoft Access, unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: Oddly enough, " I have to use Microsoft Access, unfortunately" does not really encourage me.

Comment: @Remou how so? I learned SQL (not to any great standard) with MySQL and since my new job requires me to use Access I find that things that were easy with MySQL are either impossible or require ridiculous workarounds. That's why I say "unfortunately".

Comment: @Remou if I wasn't using Access Kyle's answer would have worked (Maybe it would work in Access 2007 but I'm using 2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reluctant to answer this as the thought of even assisting in the development of a database with a table name  [Customer Brand Purchases] makes me feel a little bit sick.

My Access SQL is a little rusty but I am 98% certain this will work:

```
SELECT   CBP.Email, CBP.Brand AS [Favourite Brand ID]
FROM    [Customer Brand Purchases] AS CBP
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  [Email], MAX(CountofBrand) AS [MaxCountofBrand]
            FROM    [Customer Brand Purchases]
            GROUP BY [Email]
        ) AS [MaxCBP]
            ON CBP.Email = MaxCBP.Email
            AND CBP.CountOfBrand = MaxCBP.MaxCountOfBrand
```

The only draw back is that if a particular customer has ordered 2 brands the same amount of times then it will return 2 rows. You would need additional subqueries with MAX statements in to resolve this.

EDIT/ADDENDUM:

If it is ABSOLUTELY imperative the query returns 1 result per email address then you need to allow for the scenario where a particular email address has purchased 2 brands and equal amount of times there is no way to establish which or these is favourite as they are joint favourite. If it were me I would deal with this at application level, and Concatenate favourite brands into one string. However, it can be done in SQL just be aware that one or more brands could be hidden using this:

```
SELECT   CBP.Email, CBP.Brand AS [Favourite Brand ID]
FROM    [Customer Brand Purchases] AS CBP
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  CBP.Email, MAX(CBP.Brand) AS MaxBrand
            FROM    [Customer Brand Purchases] AS CBP
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  [Email], MAX(CountofBrand) AS MaxCountofBrand
                        FROM    [Customer Brand Purchases]
                        GROUP BY [Email]
                    ) AS MaxCBP
                        ON CBP.Email = MaxCBP.Email
                        AND CBP.CountOfBrand = MaxCBP.MaxCountOfBrand
            GROUP BY Email
        ) AS MaxCBP
            ON CBP.Email = MaxCBP.Email
            AND CBP.Brand = MaxCBP.Brand
```

Comment: Ha! `[Customer Brand Purchases]` is actually a query, that's why it has a terrible but descriptive name. I'm querying a query like it was a table (that may be why my original attempt is timing out). I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately, it said there was an error in the FROM clause 3 times and produced an empty result.

Comment: +1 - I'm not up on the MSAccess dialect, but that looks like what I'd try on DB2, and should be largely portable elsewhere regardless.  If the combination [`email`, `brand_id`] isn't unique (given that this is a summary table), they have an even larger problem, so that's not likely an issue here.  And we can only hope that this knowledge won't be used for _too_ nefarious a purpose by the OP (or his marketing department).

Comment: Access will accept a query name which doesn't include spaces: Customer_Brand_Purchases.  And without embedded spaces, you don't need to bracket the name when you reference it in other SQL statements.

Comment: I have edited the query slightly, I had missed an 'AS' out during an alias I think. I have tested the attached in access now and it seems to work for me (Access 2007).

Comment: @GarethD I don't doubt your SQL for a second but it's still producing more than one result for an email address that has purchased from more than one brand. I've got to leave work now but I will come back to this on Monday. This has to be close to what I need.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for duplicates is as follows. If a particular email has purchased brand1 15 times, brand2 10 times and brand3 15 times, the subquery will identify that the favourite brand has been purchsased 15 times, but when joining back to [Customer Brand Purchases] there is ambiguity as to whether this is brand1 or brand3 so the query will return 2 rows for this email address. This is what I meant by additional MAX statements to limit it to 1 result if it is imperative only 1 is returned. I've added to my answer to limit it to 1 result per customer

Comment: Hi @GarethD, this is still not working for me however I appreciate your help. I'm sure it will help me to work it out eventually.

Answer (score 2):

So your GROUP BY clause should list the values that the aggregate data function MAX() should collapse into.  I just did this in SQLite (because there's no way I'm going to open Microsoft Access):

```
sqlite> create table purchases ( email varchar(255), brand_id int, order_count int );

sqlite> select * from purchases;

sqlite> insert into purchases values( 'customer@gmail.com', 89, 10 );
sqlite> insert into purchases values( 'another@gmail.com', 193, 32 );
sqlite> insert into purchases values( 'duplicate@gmail.com', 20, 2 );
sqlite> insert into purchases values( 'duplicate@gmail.com', 47, 5 );

sqlite> select * from purchases
customer@gmail.com|89|10
another@gmail.com|193|32
duplicate@gmail.com|20|2
duplicate@gmail.com|47|5

sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select email, brand_id, max( order_count )from purchases group by email;

email              brand_id    order_count
-----------------  ----------  -----------
another@gmail.com  193         32               
customer@gmail.co  89          10               
duplicate@gmail.c  47          5
```

I believe that's what you're looking for, right?

Comment: I thought you'd cracked it then but for some reason when I run the same in access it's isn't grouping the emails. Despite the `GROUP BY [Email]` clause I'm still getting duplicate emails.

Comment: I think the reason is that Access makes you include all columns that you are selecting in the `GROUP BY` so I can't just say `GROUP BY [Email]` I have to also group by brand_id which is why I'm still getting duplicates. I hate Access.

Comment: I'm surprised it's working at all, given that `brand_id` is neither aggregated (nonsensical) or included (explicitly, at least) in the `GROUP BY` (which would result in duplicate rows, regardless).  Is this some quirk of SQLite?  This statement won't run on DB2... At least it's not giving a random result for `brand_id` (I'm lookin at you, mySQL)...

Comment: Curious, as I use MS Access almost never, is it SQLite or MS Access that's deviating from "Normal SQL" in this case?  I know this would also work in MySQL -- but was surprised that DB2 has the same limitation.

Comment: It's sqlite that's odd here. X-Zero's correct. I don't know mysql so I can't comment.

Answer (score 2):

Gareth's answer looked correct to me.  I tested my own attempt using the data from your base query which I stored in a table I named Customer_Brand_Purchases.  I also renamed the Brand_ID column.

```
SELECT
    c1.Email,
    c1.Brand_ID AS [Favourite Brand ID]
FROM
    Customer_Brand_Purchases AS c1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            Email,
            Max(CountOfOrders) AS MaxOfCountOfOrders
        FROM Customer_Brand_Purchases
        GROUP BY Email
        ) AS c2
    ON
        (c1.Email = c2.Email)
        AND (c1.CountOfOrders = c2.MaxOfCountOfOrders)
ORDER BY c1.Email;
```

I can confirm this works in Access 2007, meaning it produces the output I think you want  without error messages.

```
Email               Favourite Brand ID
another@gmail.com                  193
customer@gmail.com                  89
duplicate@gmail.com                 47
```

However my query is nearly the same as Gareth's version.  The only reason I can offer why mine might work for you when his doesn't is that I avoided using square brackets within the subquery.

In certain situations (the details of which are unclear to me), Access' query designer will rewrite a subquery from this form:

```
SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT something FROM YourTable) AS q
```

to this ...

```
SELECT q.* FROM [SELECT something FROM YourTable]. AS q
```

And in that second form, the db engine will choke if the subquery includes square brackets.  Incidentally, this is one reason to avoid using object names which require bracketing ... such as names which include spaces.

OTOH, if my version also fails for you, I suspect your base query source is too complex for the db engine to cope with when you use it here.  If so, follow Philippe's advice to build on the original source tables rather than the [Customer Brand Purchases] query.

Answer (score 1):

Following one of the comments you made, it seems that you are here buidling queries on queries.

If you really want to know your customer's favorite brands, I am sure it would be a lot easier to go back to the original tables, building a query on your clients, order lines, product references, and 'brand' tables.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure you're right. When I'm presented with a problem I tend to dive in and try and roughly solve it as quickly as possible and then refine the solution down later which is why I'm querying a hastily written query. Perhaps I need to think about the problem a bit more.

Comment: Oh ! And it'll help you get rid of the [Customer Brand Purchases] name in your script. This alone will please #garethD!